# Angular Material v15 Theme + Typography, default text not styled

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-15

When I customize the theme to set a font...

1. some text gets properly styled (e.g. `<mat-card-title> <mat-card-action>` etc)
2. but some other does not (e.g. `<p> <span> <mat-card-content>`) and default to Roboto... **Shouldn't those take the body-1 style?** Note that I am using mat-card as an example, but the same happens with other components.
   https://material.angular.io/guide/typography

[image]

Minimal steps to repro:

- Add a Google font to index.html
- Configure styles in styles.scss so that the new font is the default for all levels (should be used everywhere)

```
$theme-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$theme-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);

$my-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: "'Nerko One', cursive",
);

$theme: mat.define-light-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: $theme-primary,
      accent: $theme-accent,
    ),
    typography: $my-typography,
  )
);
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

Here is an example, you can see that the title etc are styled, but not the content of the card:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wan6f9?file=src/app/card-actions-example.html

I tried a few approaches, including configuring each level which did not work. The only thing that works is to hardcode the default to the root of the document, which I would rather not do.

Answer (score 28):

I had exactly the same symptoms and desperately added
`@include mat.all-component-typographies($typography);` in addition to the `@include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);` present in the documentation.

Where `$typography` is basically the same as described by the OP.

Then all the styles kicked in as expected.

Comment: This answer put me on the right track, thank you! I also had to add `class="mat-typography"` to the body of the document to have the styles final show up in `div`, `p` etc. Had tried one or the other, but not both at the same time :@

Comment: This is absolute madness @Julien. But it worked *__*. Thanks a lot

Comment: After much wasted time I found the samething. Starting with v15 I had to add `@include mat.all-component-typographies($mpt-app-theme);` for the global material styles to work (`<body class="mat-typography">`). I figured it was included with `all-component-themes` but apparently not.

Comment: Hey I was able to apply font-family, but the config for headline-1 for typography didnt work at all :/

Answer (score 10):

In my case I used the two "legacy" mixins to keep my "not-yet-migrated-to-MDC" code working as before:

- `mat.define-legacy-typography-config()`
- `mat.all-legacy-component-themes($theme)`

But this means you would need to keep using the now [legacy](https://rc.material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#what-has-changed) components by importing them accordingly. These "legacy" imports should be automatically created with a migration when using `ng update @angular/material@15` (see [Angular update guide](https://update.angular.io/?v=14.0-15.0)) or when using `nx migrate latest` in a [Nx Workspace](https://nx.dev).

In `material.module.ts` of your [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wan6f9-abtk2f?file=src/material.module.ts):

```js
import { MatLegacyCardModule as MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-card';
import { MatLegacyButtonModule as MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-button';
```

Comment: mat.all-legacy-component-themes($theme) was what I was missing, thanks!

Comment: This also saved us, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

All I did to fix it was wrapping `@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);`
inside `body { ... }`, so the theme declaration looks like this:

```
body {
    @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
}
```

Looks like this mixin has to be a child of any element to work properly.

Comment: font-family is still not being applied in my case

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using legacy components, and adding this seemed to fix some issues:

```
@include mat.all-legacy-component-themes($theme);
```

BUT, it seemed to override some of my custom theme styles, so I had to replace mat.all-legacy-component-themes import with individual imports:

```
@include mat.legacy-button-theme($theme);
@include mat.legacy-form-field-theme($theme);
```

Also, be mindful that the order of the @includes matters.